# CodeNarc failing on DuplicateStringLiteral rule for strings included in ignoreStrings

Tags: gradle, groovy, codenarc

I'm using the CodeNarc plug for Gradle with CodeNarc 1.1. I am using the DuplicateStringLiteral rule and passing in ignoreStrings: ['1', '2'] in the config file but the rule is not respecting the values I'm passing in.  It's a groovy config file, section looks like:

```
DuplicateStringLiteral (
        ignoreStrings: ['1', '2']
)
```

I am also using DuplicateNumberLiteral and defined the ignoreNumbers property the same way and that seems to be working fine, so I don't think I have the syntax wrong. The report seems to pick up the ignored values as well as it shows this line in the definition for the rule:

> The ignoreStrings property ([1, 2]) can optionally specify a comma-separated list of Strings to ignore.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation shows the default value of ignoreStrings to be an empty String... not an empty List.  This makes me think that when it says *The optional comma-separated list of Strings that should be ignored (i.e., not cause a violation).*, it means to put the list (note lack of capitalization) of  comma-separated strings in a single String value for the property.

TL;DR  Try:

```
DuplicateStringLiteral (
        ignoreStrings: '1,2'
)
```

Comment: That was it. Interesting, I would have thought that would be treated as one string. Must have to escape the comma somehow if you want your string. I tried a few variations and was unable to get a string that had a comma in it ignored. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might consider *not* populating this rule (we don't).   If you have classes that just need to have duplicate literals, consider using `@SuppressWarnings('DuplicateStringLiteral')` annotating the class/methods involved.   This allows the rule to still work, and gives you an annotation to look for and justify during code reviews.